# Elasticsearch Hashtable functionality

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to implement a high speed and efficient search engine for a chat platform.
Messages are broadcasted into channels. I have a module that extract important words in messages.

So I have important words and channel name. I want to make a HashTable that make a index from "channel+word" that stores message ID in message database (ScyllaDB) to find a specific word in channels quickly.

I was going to use my manual HashTable algorithm that uses XHash to get ID of a hash field and store it in ElasticSearch.

Do ES support this functionality? Indexing two fields together for fast querying? Or I need to implement it by myself?